# Issue with perl one-liner searching for pipe at end of line

Tags: regex, perl, replace, pipe

I have some files had some bad regex search and replace happen to them and it has left me with various lines that end in a "|".  I'm trying to create a perl oneliner to fix the issue, but can't seem to match the "|" at the end of the line.

Created an example file that only has the problem lines in it.

```
$ cat ad.sh.bak2
    echo "dbconfig Db side ..."  |
date |
   echo "ALERT !!! THIS IS PRODUCTION SERVER" |
  echo "ERROR: Environment cannot be started! (retvalue=$retvalue)" |
$
```

Have tried the following (changed the one-liner below to just print on match instead of my normal s///g):

```
    $ cat ad.sh.bak2 |perl -ne '/\|$/ && print'
    $ cat ad.sh.bak2 |perl -ne '/\|$ */ && print'
    $
```

If I get rid of the "$", it matches the lines (and others I don't want).  I have confirmed that there are no whitespace or unprintable characters after the "|"  (vim "set list" shows the $ immediately after each "|").

Not sure what I am doing wrong in my regex.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Ok, as expected, I'm an idiot. Tried your s/\|$//gm, Chankey, and it didn't work on my file, but it did when I copy pasted into a new file. Took a closer look at my test file (and the file it was generated from) and realized they were dos uploaded that hadn't been converted to unix (overlooked the "dos" flag at the bottom of vim too). So my match was missing the ^M.

Once I stripped those, it worked! Thanks!

P.S. - I know that "perl -ne '/\|*/ && print' does not do "search and replace", I did that just to test the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use search and replace. You are currently just matching the regex.

Below works fine.

```
$ cat test | perl -pe 's/\|$//'
    echo "dbconfig Db side ..."  
date 
   echo "ALERT !!! THIS IS PRODUCTION SERVER" 
  echo "ERROR: Environment cannot be started! (retvalue=$retvalue)"
```

However, you do not need to pipe cat to perl. Just pass filename to oneliner.

Assuming file name is test, below are the contents

```
$ cat test 
    echo "dbconfig Db side ..."  |
date |
   echo "ALERT !!! THIS IS PRODUCTION SERVER" |
  echo "ERROR: Environment cannot be started! (retvalue=$retvalue)" |
```

Below is Perl oneliner which removes | at the end of each line

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/\|$//gm' test
```

Content of file after replacement

```
$ cat test 
    echo "dbconfig Db side ..."  
date 
   echo "ALERT !!! THIS IS PRODUCTION SERVER" 
  echo "ERROR: Environment cannot be started! (retvalue=$retvalue)"
```

---

If you prefer a program over oneliner then below would work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = 'test';
my $outputfile = 'test.out';
open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;
open (my $ofh, ">", $outputfile) or die $!;
while(my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/(.*)\|$/$1/gm;
    print $ofh "$line\n";
}
```